# Exclude androidx.lifecycle

Tags: android

I had to change something in my gradle.build file, now I get an error. I think I know where the problem is, but I am not able to solve.

This is the error:

`Duplicate class androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelLazy found in modules lifecycle-viewmodel-2.5.1-runtime (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.5.1) and lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx-2.3.1-runtime (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.3.1) Duplicate class androidx.lifecycle.ViewTreeViewModelKt found in modules lifecycle-viewmodel-2.5.1-runtime (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.5.1) and lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx-2.3.1-runtime (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.3.1)`

What I have tried so far:

```
configurations.implementation {
    exclude group: 'androidx.lifecycle' , module:'lifecycle-viewmodel-2.5.1-runtime'
}
```

But honestly, I have no clue what I do - my experience is Java not gradle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
configurations.implementation {
    exclude group: 'androidx.lifecycle' , module:'lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx'
}
```

Is all that was needed

Answer (score 0):

I think you should make sure `androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel` and `androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx` have same version. Check them out in the build.gradle file.

Comment: As mentioned, i am not good at gradle. I understand the error, but I couldn't find what to exclude